# Why are my routes not working when deploying Ionic Vue app to Heroku?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, heroku

**Problem**

Hi, I am experiencing an issue when I deploy my Ionic Vue app to Heroku. Deploying the app works fine, but when I try to go to the different routes I get:

> 2021-03-10T15:38:19.040914+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/login" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=84a122a5-d049-4779-8b7e-876d6e32ba18 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=388 protocol=https

And I experience the same behavior when running heroku local.

However, when I run ionic serve the app works fine.

**Information/setup**

To deploy the app to Heroku I added an index.js file to the top level of my project containing the following:

```js
const servestatic = require('serve-static')
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();
app.use(servestatic(path.join(path.resolve(), 'dist')));
app.listen(port, () => {console.log("API server started on " + port);});
```

Where dist is the build folder. I then added the start script to my package.json:

> "start": "node index.js"

This way, Heroku knows to try npm start as I don't have a Procfile. The deploy in itself works fine, but when I go to any route in the app I get a 404 error. The complete Heroku log can be seen here:

```
2021-03-10T15:07:19.114910+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-03-10T15:07:22.144208+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-10T15:07:22.144223+00:00 app[web.1]: > QuizApp@0.0.1 start /app
2021-03-10T15:07:22.144223+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2021-03-10T15:07:22.144224+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-10T15:07:22.310147+00:00 app[web.1]: API server started on 43373
2021-03-10T15:07:23.517856+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-03-10T15:07:25.199126+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d2376e6.a351546d.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=5d0a42b8-88a5-4487-b556-ab029b9b8c1b fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=22ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:07:25.199127+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d0c1ca1.a8741f4e.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=a76b4bf7-ab00-4717-99f2-bcc2c3b5dd2f fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:07:25.201223+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d0b33e3.64be60e2.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=2e54039e-140d-42e8-b95b-ceee8846463f fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.655934+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=7fb7de29-e38c-4f2e-b0bc-5272911d48a7 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.735029+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/app.d9a56adb.css" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=283a0810-bcc6-4519-b855-4f52bb650518 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.786315+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/chunk-vendors.190e707f.css" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=1a5c8021-87fc-4da1-9c0a-e9cac3f21906 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.832745+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/app.8e02537b.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=0d949d71-7ed5-47ac-90d3-5b121dd1878b fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.836261+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-008cd3d6.3005bdb1.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=d128ea28-75f6-4f22-b3cc-4b56befe4d1e fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.837172+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-02c995b5.fa6e2cf9.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=8c4075f2-b71e-4b10-80d2-92a8b742c064 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.837719+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-vendors.c30fbadd.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=b3036e6a-eff8-40b5-a8ea-ec739c24eab0 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=240 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.858978+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-09155df3.d36d2ee2.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=ad848cc1-1b9e-4901-af10-da702b932082 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.861071+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-09162720.76641c07.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=ef9db905-03ba-434f-850d-3e01f0418f04 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.881960+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-097e0872.60b51ae3.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=b61e7cad-a8fb-4c95-9ab8-b9abdc6564f3 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.888033+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-1dbc15a2.b0f42ac1.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=8494c564-5e79-4684-96e7-026a4193e76c fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.890513+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-0e93a01c.07ea6d42.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=e243969a-08b8-41a0-93c3-f6399135d72b fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.900007+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-1f3fa45a.5984dc83.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=ccc243c0-4af4-4c09-8ced-e1dbc435f7aa fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.909957+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-21a76241.81e05e6d.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=42c4a87d-2422-406e-870f-f9338a7d8b6f fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.913642+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-25d83ca8.11d75d2c.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=bc59049c-fe49-430b-a61f-2bafc0239b2b fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.930047+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d0a3ffc.ae92ec73.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=97226500-ca0d-4cb3-9e75-85d3cff4400c fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.940764+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d0a463b.01d977a4.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=f3bc3cd9-df24-4fe5-aac3-a828a0b9ee04 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.955585+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d0b62ff.8c63fa0c.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=1d1782a9-7b5a-4b6e-bef3-abc66c816723 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.959062+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d0b33e3.64be60e2.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=f3b438d6-61c6-4e59-9349-520c72261c8d fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms status=200 bytes=1232 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.964642+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d0bd1c8.f49bd318.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=fab5acf9-8423-49af-aaee-9efee3d239e8 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.965324+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d0c073f.51dd8b12.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=fd8423eb-65c9-4f29-a493-9fea46d4fa25 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.982461+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d0c1ca1.a8741f4e.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=6daa7472-ab4e-4312-b53f-d46a1ca3ed78 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=2526 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:14.994530+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d0d43da.8588ac75.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=ad5486ca-a461-45f7-a4d8-eafc347140f1 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.006033+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-34f7327c.e2c5d5e5.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=16954373-220b-493a-81dd-a45bf2f58de6 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.011424+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d0d6f0e.75ac8d11.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=3dc18002-c26d-41b2-b130-868cf0af3cb1 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.018915+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d0da04a.219ce0c4.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=1660c9c9-708b-4486-ad0a-3879ad343336 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.019397+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d0e19fd.55dbdcb5.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=5f1f9858-4844-4cc4-a8c0-cbdba346d637 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.035983+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d0e5812.a4b8f3a4.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=d15bb728-cfbb-4ade-8a75-4be353e6e852 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.044346+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d208702.36ed287c.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=236d11c1-4c2c-4b5c-8823-b79c0000247f fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.059948+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d209619.2be46e60.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=d76c8437-7cd5-4537-af51-aec1ecf4b47c fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.076572+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d213189.4a1e81e6.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=d85b899e-2d8d-4f0f-b6bb-554c0abcf9e8 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.083776+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d2376e6.a351546d.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=960b1c5f-42e4-4912-86d0-6e043f9dc82b fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=2049 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.085811+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d218068.b78d2933.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=2aa9d94c-1084-4da1-b0ad-c0d0848aa65f fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.098292+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d21da73.08cbbce9.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=d8210f86-15cc-4e32-a755-c4ab0026c6bb fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.109074+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d2304d2.2178b8d3.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=17a52c04-b5e4-490a-b3e1-987bdd4c3f2f fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.128780+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-30dd9750.cfb0b2f6.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=6df6ce29-84d3-4864-b353-f8f58e36bbfb fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.132614+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-34f7327c.e2c5d5e5.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=3791b40f-c4b3-475f-992a-1f9c4b38a379 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.134374+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-2d2376e6.a351546d.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=cbf132f1-f667-469e-8b30-a0c083c6a206 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.138324+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-37f2300e.53406572.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=56791ad3-4622-471b-b713-feed4b7527ef fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.156229+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-3ed29de3.d139ee8e.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=cad2383c-eb42-4f1a-87d6-54de2909b7f1 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.158145+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-41c0f7a4.7cc0c87a.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=b9fd4706-1138-48d2-bd93-393ba0140d3a fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.178908+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-462c869e.fcf44c39.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=a4440bb7-12e4-43df-af18-bcffb27a3bc1 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.186809+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-541ea42d.91486697.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=1ec532cc-5341-4880-bee1-e5a42aeabc92 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.187141+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-504c4825.0546e26d.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=d6039ab0-40f2-48f1-a26d-47d70bd38af4 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.189793+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-54bbd082.96b284ec.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=48cac0de-9070-4694-9aee-3556e48fd9aa fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.205002+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-59d4c87c.1a275868.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=50bb2591-4337-46b3-a1c8-20bb75219554 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.210092+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-5a8ac886.b93cf59b.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=efc14206-61f3-46af-8c13-4c7fc28d196f fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.228744+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-5ff96a24.cec90723.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=659814fd-7a8d-4471-84a0-e4d735e7c126 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.236275+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-69eb8776.8a325ef9.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=114ca4cb-bd7f-46c7-80b5-840f35038e91 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.242372+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-7548ca2d.5a742f4a.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=ec23371e-dbfe-4458-9469-fb1ab5385803 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.244164+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-6d375f34.2ac204ac.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=72148630-f160-47ee-8077-0468edb5841e fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.254369+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-79f1dac7.5ca7503f.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=75c17385-c699-4b2b-bf15-682ac6ba3c07 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.259775+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-858cd918.736290f5.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=26af0cc1-a87d-4538-ba8e-8e0dcb2cfee9 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.285250+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-8bb7f81e.7cdbaf55.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=af465e68-5172-4211-af1b-a8966f4f34f5 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.290953+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-a9395c36.663597ef.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=95d51e49-9f2d-40a4-ac5f-ebdd2bbd2165 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.296644+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-c53d26f0.34a2d403.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=a1f1ba48-ac69-4555-8026-d898d5e341ee fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.300871+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-c567cc2a.b3489079.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=97d78710-1dc5-48ab-a32b-efe4ef48d1ab fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.304379+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-d0e8aa0a.ab28a97c.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=08ee3e91-c008-43a5-b677-7adfc54a260c fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.308974+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-d8413eac.3ea80a0d.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=85fcbd7b-cf95-4873-8ae9-90ce2fc26f62 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.334340+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-eaa2b130.63c2ebdf.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=c6de46eb-e9f1-403b-b4d1-7ef477c079c1 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.339967+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/chunk-f858ef4e.10203b06.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=44ca21e8-0c8d-46c9-ad13-c03e61bcd40e fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.352750+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/polyfills-core-js.6d1a8426.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=8ba36748-a28a-4aaf-b99c-53e9a821edde fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:15.356141+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/polyfills-dom.5c1a31ff.js" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=1837a1a1-49c0-4b62-9c1f-5151b4c38820 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:38:19.040914+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/login" host=quiz-app-client.herokuapp.com request_id=84a122a5-d049-4779-8b7e-876d6e32ba18 fwd="212.10.104.241" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=388 protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:39:15.484695+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2021-03-10T15:39:15.487145+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2021-03-10T15:39:16.739321+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-03-10T15:39:16.935588+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

When I run the app using ionic serve and go to the 8100 port the app works fine and there aren't any issues. I am using Vue 3.0, ionic/vue 5.4.0 and I am using the Vue router. I wonder if I am missing some routing setup in the index.js. If I need to add any additional information please let me know. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT**

Here are the dependencies and scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.4.5",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.4.5",
    "@ionic/vue": "^5.4.0",
    "@ionic/vue-router": "^5.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^8.2.2",
    "ionicons": "^5.4.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.11",
    "vue": "^3.0.0-0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-rc.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.4.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
    "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-0"
  }
```

Comment: Please show us the `devDependencies` block of your `package.json`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I added it to the post, thank you for taking the time to look at this.